# Writing a word into every txt file in a folder

Tags: command-line, scripts

How can I write the word "cat" into every .txt file in a folder?

Answer (score 21):

A simple for will do the work:

```
for i in ./*.txt; do echo 'cat' >> "$i"; done;
```

This will get a list of all txt files in current directory, loops throughout them and `echo` cat into them (append to the content). you can change `>>` to `>`, to overwrite the files content with cat.

Another thing you can do is using `tee` to redirect a stream to multiple files.

To append:

```
echo "cat" | tee -a *.txt
```

To overwrite:

```
echo "cat" | tee *.txt
```

Comment: what is the con to use `echo "cat" >>  *.txt`?

Comment: @hakermania that should fail with `ambiguous redirect`

Answer (score 13):

If the files are not empty you can use `sed` without looping. To add `cat` at the start:

```
sed 'i\cat' *.txt
```

To add at the end:

```
sed 'a\cat' *.txt
```

To add after the second line:

```
sed '2 a\cat' *.txt
```

To add before lines with `foo` in them:

```
sed '/foo/ i\cat' *.txt
```

It doesn't work on empty files though. Kind of a bug.

(To actually write to the files after testing you need the `-i` option: `sed -i 'a\cat' *.txt`)

Comment: I hate sed :)), cause theres a lot of things you can do with it and I'm not aware of them  :))

Comment: @Ravexina `sed` is my jam ;)

Comment: why does `'i\cat'` use the backslash instead of slash?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc the backslash is optional actually,  you can also put `'icat'` or `i cat`. The backslash is conventional I believe. You can't use forwardslash - it will be literally inserted

Answer (score 4):

Python approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(i,'w') as fd:
        fd.write("cat\n")
```

- it uses`sys` module to iterate over command-line arguments
- each command-line argument will be open as file for writing
- "cat" with newline will be written to file before going to next

Usage would be as `./add_cat.py *.txt` , which would operate on all `.txt` files in current working directory. Improvement to this could include using command-line argument #1 as string to write instead of hardcoding "cat" there.