# sed command doesn't insert text in a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

This is my sample test `sed` command to insert a sample text to an empty text file.

```
sed -i "$ a\My test text" Desktop/test.txt
sed -i '$ a\My test text' Desktop/test.txt
```

I tried with both the options, one with single quotes and another with double quotes. But both the commands fail to write that text into my `test.txt` file. Why are these commands not working?

Comment: Is it an empty file by any chance?

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong, I tested both commands and both are adding `My test text` at the end of the file, unless it is an empty file (good catch @pomsky).

Comment: @pomsky; Yes. It is an empty file.

Comment: @pim: Now I added a empty line in that file and tried to add. Now it has been added. But I want to add it to a empty file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `a` and `i` commands don't work on empty files. As you have mentioned the `~/Desktop/test.txt` is an empty file, both the commands you tried fail to meet your purpose. The same commands will work fine with a non-empty file.

You may try `echo` instead of `sed` to achieve your goal.

See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/903572/) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up about sed failing with empty files.  Was driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this issue, but `echo` didn't work with my particular use case which was looping through an array and printing the contents.  I just couldn't get the formatting right with `echo`, so needed to keep the `sed`. But as @pomsky rightly notes, it doesn't like empty files. Ugh.

### Solution:

So for my particular use-case, I `echo`'ed a blank space into the newly created file:

```
if [ ! -s file ]; then echo "" > file; fi
```

The test will not evaluate as `true` because although the file is empty, it does not have a size greater than zero on a clean file created by `touch`- thus my use of negation `!`. **A blank space will now be echoed on the first line.**

When I subsequently execute:

```
sed -i "1i blah" file
```

Now my `sed` will work on the "empty" file. I didn't actually print "*blah*", but looped through the contents of array ;-).

If you're in a similar situation where you can't just use `echo` in lieu of `sed`, I hope this saves you cycles solving the same problem that drove me bananas...